# share database with native android and html5 (sqlite error no such table)

Tags: android, html, database, sqlite, android-webview

I'm trying to create an application that share database with native android and html.
I initialize the below code and enable database for my webview page. But at the webview page, I get no such table (hybrid_user) when I update the database. I'm not sure what I missed here.

**Database**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private SQLiteDatabase helper;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="hybrid_db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;
private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";


public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "DBHelper");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hybrid_user (" +
            "tableid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "userid TEXT," +
            "password TEXT," +
            "mobile TEXT," +
            "createdate TIMESTAMP default current_timestamp);");
}
```

**Activity**

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/com.example.hybrid/hybrid_db");
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+userid+"\")");
        }
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, 
                long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota,
                WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater){
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(204801);
        }
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
var hybrid_user = null;
    function errorHandler(transaction, error){
        alert('Error:'+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
        return true;
    }
    window.onerror = errorHandler;
    try{
        if(window.openDatabase){
            var shortName = 'hybrid_db';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'Hybrid Database';
            var maxSize = 204801;
            hybrid_user = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            alert("alert: "+hybrid_user);
        }
        else{
            alert("Database is not supported");
        }           
    }
    catch(e){
        if(e == 2){
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        }
        else{
            alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
        }
        return;
    }



    function updateRecord(){
        hybrid_user.transaction(
                function(transaction){
                    transaction.executeSql("UPDATE hybrid_user SET mobile=? WHERE userid ='"+document.getElementById("userid")+"'", [mobileNum]);
                    alert("mobileNum:" +mobileNum);
                    alert("userid:" +document.getElementById("userid"));
        });
    }
</script>

<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Hybrid Application</legend>
        <p>

            <label>UserName: </label> <p id="userid"></p>
        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number :</label>
            <input type = "text"
                        id = "mobileNum" />
        </p>
            <button type="button" 
            onclick="updateRecord()">Submit</button>    
                <div id="output"></div> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

I get `alert:[object Database]` from the `alert("alert:" +hybrid_user);`. But still I get sqlite error no such table. `sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table:hybrid_user`

Comment: yor code have following error : http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=SECURITY_ERR:+DOM+Exception+18&oq=SECURITY_ERR:+DOM+Exception+18&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i7j0.872823.875570.3.877159.4.4.0.0.0.0.1459.2428.0j1j1j5-1j0j1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.plt4qwgsBwg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bmk&fp=d8971a0b118526f4&biw=1366&bih=667

Comment: The database path is wrong. You shouldn't hardcode paths anyhow. See this for getting the database path: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String) Also, I didn't see in your code where you created the database.

Comment: I tried non-hardcode path as well but I'm getting the same result, in my DBHelper class is where I create the database table.

Answer (score 0):

The path to db is incorrect, you are missing "databases" directory.
It should be: `/data/data/com.example.hybrid/databases/hybrid_db`,
instead of: `/data/data/com.example.hybrid/hybrid_db`

Comment: I tried that too. But I'm getting the same result "sqlite error-no such table"

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try to this:-

```
 webView.getSettings().getDatabasePath();

getDatabasePath()
```

will give you by default path of database

basically its `/data/data/package_name/databases/db_name`

and check your query related stuff i.e open db or update

**update** :-I am sure that error in reading `index.html` in your assets folder.

try something like this:-

```
web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", index.html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

or

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: Umm... That basically returns as empty. There is nothing in `getDatabasePath()` if we did not `setDatabasePath()`. Tried it out.

Comment: but you are passing DATABASE_NAME in construcotr..it should work with out setDatabasePath db...remove your setDatabasePath()  instead of this use getDatabasePath()

Comment: Yes, I did remove setDatabasePath() and replace with getDatabasePath(). The result I get out of it is basically empty (null) there is no referred path.

Comment: Are you able to real your index.html file..can u please debug your this line and see you are doing proper or not   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Comment: Umm... I get my sqlite error when I'm trying to update my database which take place in my index.html  (`updateRecord()`). Which means the program able to read and execute my index.html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27166/discussion-between-cobra-ajgar-and-issaczh)

Answer (score 0):

Since API Level 19, WebSettings.setDatabasePath is deprecated, that means there is no longer guaranteed method to find the database file created by WebView.

I found the db file usually in /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/app_database/hybrid_db.db